# How to deal with double password prompt

Tags: bash, passwords, pipe

I have a CLI app that prompts for password confirmation **twice** in a row. Piping a password like this does not work:

```
echo password | cliapp secure operation
```

There is no flag in that CLI app for disabling double password prompt as well. I want to automate this command, and call it from my golang app. Are there any workarounds or solutions for this?

Comment: `echo 'foo\nbar' | cliapp` ?

Comment: @navigante : Well, you pipe only one password, so this can't work. But first of all: Does `cliapp` read the password from stdin or directly from the tty? If it does not request stdin, piping will be useless anyway.

Comment: [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) might be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) does exactly what I needed to do.